# How to use a subproject of a drifferent gradle multiproject

Tags: gradle

I am trying to create a helper classes multi project of which a can reuse subprojects in different projects. This way I can reuse functionality like email and parsing xmls over all the applications I'm going to build in the future.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this but until now I have not been able to find best practices for this situation. My project setup would look something like:

```
Helpers (root)
 -Emailer
 -XmlParser

HelpersUser(Root)

HelpersUser2(Root)
 -SomeSubProject
 -AnotherSubProject
```

Now I'm trying to get HelperUser1 to use Emailer and HelperUser2 to use XmlParser (and maybe also emailer).

It could be that this is not at all best practice and I would be better off just building helper jars and using those in my HelperUser projects. If so, I'd also like to know. However I'm trying to achieve a setup in which all code is dynamic and the latest is always used (and tested by jenkins to make sure nothing breaks before distributing).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that Emailer and XmlParser will be already built by the time you're trying to build HelpersUser1 and 2?

Comment: It can be if it needs to be! I'm looking for the best way to achieve code sharing into other projects and basically can do it any way I want, i'm just looking for a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can arbitrarily add any filesystem classfiles or jars as dependency to any project.

So your HelperUser projects would have dependencies in one of the following ways:

```
dependencies {
    compile  files('Helpers/a.jar', 'Helpers/b.jar')
    compile  fileTree(dir: 'Helpers/build', include: '*.jar')
    compile  files("$Helpers/build/classes")
}
```

BTW, to sort of address the last part of your question, you can use the `+` wildcard to imply the latest version available in all declared repos.

```
compile "junit:junit:4.+"
```

The `+` can become a lottery though and fail in unanticipated ways.